# How to refresh the Listview Itemsource? WPF Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview which provides me a list of all the people that are participating in an event. The event is selected in a combobox and the listview should get the participants from a List<> out of the Database.. I want to do this everytime the selection is changing. I must warn you that i am quite new at this. But i already tried a lot of examples and codes from the internet but they just wont work.. I use the following code:

C#

```
    private void cbEvenement_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this is he eventID extracted from the list by using the Selected index
        evid = _evenementen[cbEvenement.SelectedIndex].EvenementID;
        //I give the EventID to the Method in my database connector 
        //to get the right participants from the right event.
        aanmeldingen = Connect.EvenementAanmeldingen(evid);

        // getting everything ready for the listview, i have a constructor class
        foreach (var aanmelding in aanmeldingen)
        {
            aanmeldingclass.Add(new AanmeldingEvenement()
            {
                Voornaam = aanmelding.voornaam,
                Achternaam = aanmelding.achternaam
            });


        }
        // setting the itemsource
        LVAanmeldingen.ItemsSource = aanmeldingclass;
        // saw this on the internet. But it is not working?
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(aanmeldingclass).Refresh();

    }
```

Xaml

```
                <ListView x:Name="LVAanmeldingen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="458" Margin="3,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268" ItemsSource="{Binding AanmeldingCollection}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Voornaam" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Voornaam}" ></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Achternaam" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Achternaam}" ></GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Class

```
       class AanmeldingEvenement
       {
         public string Voornaam { get; set; }
         public string Achternaam { get; set; }
       }
```

Found on the internet:

```
    private ObservableCollection<AanmeldingEvenement> Aanmeldingcollection;

    public ObservableCollection<AanmeldingEvenement> AanmeldingCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (Aanmeldingcollection == null)
            {
                Aanmeldingcollection = new ObservableCollection<AanmeldingEvenement>();
            }
            return Aanmeldingcollection;
        }
        set
        {
            Aanmeldingcollection = value;
        }
    }
```

I am really stuck here, all i want is the Listview to show me the participants and get the right participants which are connected to the event in my Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you are coding like you would do with `WinfForms`. With WPF I strongly recommend you to use `MVVM` pattern and `DataBinding`. Otherwise you are missing too much things to make WPF worth it.

So here is my answer (please ask if needed):

I built two classes to manage the events and the peoples. I decided that `People` will register to the different `Events`, but it could be the opposite, or any other solution:

```
public class People
{
     public string firstName { get; set; }
     public string lastName { get; set; }

     public List<Event> registeredEvents { get; set; }

     public People()
     {
         registeredEvents = new List<Event>();
     }
}

public class Event
{
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string anyInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have an `EventManager` that will collect the information, and do the logic. Of course you have to modify it according to your database and the other parts of your program:

```
public class EventManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
    public List<People> peoples { get; set; }

    //this is the current event that correspond to the selected event in your combobox
    private Event _currentEvent;
    public Event currentEvent
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentEvent;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentEvent != value)
            {
                _currentEvent = value;
                //when you change the selected event, you have to update the list of participants
                OnPropertyChanged("participants");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<People> participants
    {
        get
        {
            //Here is the code to retrieve the people that registered to the selected event
            return peoples.Where(p => p.registeredEvents.Contains(currentEvent)).ToList<People>();
        }
    }

    public EventManager()
    {
        events = new List<Event>();
        peoples = new List<People>();
    }

    //The following lines are specific to WPF and DataBinding
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

[Here you can find more information about `Databinding`](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/)

Then the XAML. It relies only on the DataContext:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding events}" SelectedItem="{Binding currentEvent}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding participants}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding firstName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lastName}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And finally, here is my code to add the `Data`. Of course your part should be different. The important points are the `Datacontext` and the fact that I really don't care about the `ComboBox` or the `ListView`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    EventManager eventManager = new EventManager();

    Event wedding = new Event() { name = "Wedding" };
    Event meeting = new Event() { name = "Meeting with LunaStar" };
    Event skiSession = new Event() { name = "Skiing in Oklahoma" };

    People bob = new People() { firstName = "Bob", lastName = "Raz." };
    People irina = new People() { firstName = "Irina", lastName = "Politov." };
    People kumamoto = new People() { firstName = "Kumamoto", lastName = "San" };

    bob.registeredEvents.Add(wedding);
    bob.registeredEvents.Add(meeting);
    bob.registeredEvents.Add(skiSession);

    irina.registeredEvents.Add(wedding);
    irina.registeredEvents.Add(meeting);

    kumamoto.registeredEvents.Add(meeting);
    kumamoto.registeredEvents.Add(skiSession);

    eventManager.peoples = new List<People>() { bob, irina, kumamoto };
    eventManager.events = new List<Event>() { wedding, meeting, skiSession };

    DataContext = eventManager;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i finally understand what i need to do to get it working. I build a new ap with the code you provided to play around and understand what is happening. But now i want to add a People to a registered event with the help of a textbox and the selected item in the combobox. But how do i get the selected item in the Combobox to be added in "here" , here is selected in the combobox for example bob.registeredEvents.Add(here);

Comment: There are many ways to do. If the `ComboBox` is binded to the `Event` list, you can do (under a button_click for e.g.), `bob.registeredEvents.Add(ComboBoxName.SelectedItem as Event)`. You could create some properties in the `EventManager` like `eventToRegister` and `selectedParticipant`, bind them to some `ComboBox` and do `selectedParticipant.registeredEvents.Add(eventToRegister)`.